# Trying to have an object collide and delete another object in C++

Tags: c++

So I have an assignment that requires me to have a collision happen between the Player object and an Object (a cube/pyrmaid/sphere really doesn't matter which) using a Octree for my collision calculations. Upon the collision of the Player with the Object the object needs to be deleted. I have a function as such

```
void BinPart::ProcessCollisions(int &nbrTests, int &nbrCollisions){
    if(hasChildren())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
        {
        child[i]->ProcessCollisions(nbrTests, nbrCollisions);
        }
    }
    int n = objects.size();

    if(n >= 2)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                nbrTests++;
                if(player->collidesWith(objects[j]))
                {
                    objects.erase(objects.begin() + j);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(objects[i]->collidesWith(objects[j]))
                        {
                            nbrCollisions++;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(n >= 1 && parent != NULL)
    {
        parent->ProcessBorderCollisions(this, nbrTests, nbrCollisions);
    }
}
```

currently the `player->collidesWith(objects[j]);` does not work because player is "undefined" in the header file for binPart theres a forward declaration of a base class of type Object of which all the objects are being made from. The Object *player however is in the Game.h but I need the binPart to be able to access it. I've asked one of my friends on my course what he has and his is almost identical to mine which raises questions. If theres any more info needed let me know.

Comment: So have BinPart.cpp `#include "Game.h"`.

Comment: I don't normally like to complain about grammar, but I don't know  whether `... player is "undefined" in the header file for binPart` or `in the header file for binPart theres a forward declaration ...`

Comment: Sorry, in the binPart.h header file there is a forward declaration of the class Object. The player (defined in Game.h as Object *player) is undefined in binPart.cpp yet one of my coursemates has things setup the same way as me and his works.

Comment: @Elssar I'd fix it in your post if i were you, and don't forget to proofread the rest of it

Comment: Also, where is the code above actually from? That is, what file is that? What's already included there? What includes it?

Answer (score 0):

If a source file uses something declared in a header file, include that header file in the source file, even if it's also included in another source file. Use include guards to ensure that you don't re-declare anything.

Comment: But if I include Game.h which uses BinPart.h then that would surely cause all manners of problems?

Comment: @Elssar: the .h file and the .cpp file are separate (except in that the .cpp file always includes its corresponding .h file). It's true that you want to avoid circular dependencies, however it is not necessarily a circular dependency for `binpart.cpp` to include `game.h`, which in turn includes `binpart.h`. Just make sure that `binpart.h` doesn't include `game.h`.

Comment: Just gave that a go it still doesn't like it and now I have errors that are supposedly related to syntax when I haven't even changed a thing :/ I think I'm too stressed out to even try to fix this now.

Comment: As you get different errors, you should edit your question to include them. Otherwise no one knows what's going on or how to help you. In any case, you might want to just review your logic and move more of it into `.cpp` files; really, in header files, you should have mostly forward declarations and little (if any) actual program logic.

Comment: Also, again, make sure you're using include guards: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard